# PermissionError in window after pytest

Tags: windows, pytest

I am running the python project with pytest but there is permssion error. I try with fixed with assigned the fully permission still the same issues. these issues related to pytest. I check the different stackoverflow but there is no solution to be found.

```
self = WindowsPath('C:/Users/PBC53~1.PAR/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp4jyswr0l'), missing_ok = False

def unlink(self, missing_ok=False):
    """
    Remove this file or link.
    If the path is a directory, use rmdir() instead.
    """
    try:
        self._accessor.unlink(self)
```

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird: 'C:\Users\PBC53~1.PAR\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4jyswr0l'
>
> C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\pathlib.py:1203: PermissionError

I am expecting to run pytest in the .env folder without any permission error. I have a pytest package and code also run perfectly with macos but window getting permission error.

Comment: I suppose the answer is after PermissionError: 
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Permissions are not the thing you need to worry about - your file is open somewhere else by some other process you should find out which process holds it.

Comment: I checked it and removed it again same process then I killed the main temp file which making a problem and restart doesn't work.  There is pathlib.py inside the c drive files and showing Perrmission error while running the pytest. from .venv environment. I checked the permission and aasigned the full permission still the same.

Comment: Why your test is trying to remove files that are opened by another process? You should create temp files if your intention is to test `unlink`.